# What Does the Byte[] Representation of an Image Actually Mean?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I loaded a 1 pixel image into a bitmap and then converted it to a byte[]

```
           _Image = "test.jpg";

            Bitmap testImage = new Bitmap(_Image);

            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            byte[] byteTestImage =  (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(testImage,typeof(byte[]));
```

The single pixel has RGB values (255, 116, 25). Each of these can be represented by a byte,
so I assumed that byteTestImage would correspond to this. But, byteTestImage is 635 elements in total.

What is the relationship between those bytes and the 1 pixel image?

Comment: Take a look at the [Bitmap File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: The file itself isn't just the RGB elements. It can also feature an Alpha channel (another byte), and will have file header information. For example, header info denoting that it's a JPG. When you think about it, this must exist as how else does an image know how tall or wide it is in the very least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you loaded is a JPG. It has certain additional information (width, height, EXIF data) not just colors. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Try opening it in a hex editor. You might even be able to read info about the camera used to take it.

Comment: So if I  just had a 3d array of the pixel values, and I wanted to convert it to a bitmap, I would have the individually set the pixels int the bitmap. I couldn't go the route of converting my array into a byte[], since I don't have the other information.

Comment: @user1475729: JPEG is just one format that BitMap supports. There are lots of ways to get data into a BitMap.

Answer (score 0):

There is no always RGB format for single pixel in Bitmap. It all depends on format. You can have a alfa component, you can have a palette to which martix of pixels refers to and more...

Check out: [Bitmap format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)